# Closest of a list of addresses from a location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-4

does anyone know how i can return a googlemap with pins for every location within a set radius. Don't necessarily need a specific distance from potential plotted route. I want the user to be able to specify their address (postcode) and a set distance (10,20,50 miles) and then i can show these results on a map. I have the list of postcodes, held in my database, do i need to generate something like a kml?

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a classic **Store Locator** application, which is a bit complex to detail in an SE answer.

Google have [an example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) documented, though.

Comment: cheers Andrew this is a good starter for a large part of the problem. My initial part is I have a list of addresses currently in my database which don't have latitude and longitude values, presumably I need to find a c# library which will allow me to iterate through these records and update my table with latitude and longitude values?

Comment: You certainly will need to geocode the addresses, and a C# routine is one way. You may be able to make use of a bit of Javascript as well: http://acleach.me.uk/gmaps/v3/plotaddresses.htm